# WYSIWYG - is it possible

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why doesn’t the site use a rich text editor?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28351/why-doesnt-the-site-use-a-rich-text-editor)
>   [Should the markdown renderer treat a single line break as <br>?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26011/should-the-markdown-renderer-treat-a-single-line-break-as-br)

Is there a chance to have WYSIWYG editor in SO instead of this mind boggling meta? And having ENTER as a next line not those two ridiculous two spaces etc.

Answer (score 9):

I absolutely adore markdown - and there *is* at least "what you see in the preview is what you get", along with helpful icons and shortcut keys.

One indication of how successful I view markdown to be is that now when I'm writing blog posts or emails, I naturally write backticks for code etc - and then I'm very disappointed when it doesn't format properly :(

Comment: What you see in the preview is *usually* what you get. I wonder if there's a market for WYSITPIUWYG editors.

Comment: I can't count how many times I've surround words with \*asterisks\* and expect MS Word to automatically convert them to *italic*. Grrr...

Comment: @Robert, actually I'm quite sure Microsoft Word *does* automatic conversion, if you enable it.

Answer (score 4):

I *like* SO's editor, TYVM. I only wish some of the awesome awesome keyboard shortcuts were available in the comment editor. (hint, hint, Jeff)